# _<parent_class><__method_name> pattern overrides parents <__method_name>, Why?

Tags: python, inheritance

I saw an example today of a method overriding a method in a base class that had a different name, how and *why* is this possible? And what uses could it possibly have?

```
>>> class A(object):
...   def foo(self):
...     self.__bar()
...   def __bar(self):
...     print "original"
... 
>>> class B(A):
...   def _A__bar(self):
...     print "overridden"
... 
>>> B().foo()
overridden
```

Comment: It is result of the [Python name mangling](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#atom-identifiers).

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I disagree with the possible duplicate. The cause of the behaviour is the name mangling, but the question are different.

Comment: @MattH: the answers are roughly the same, as the cause is the same. By having 100 subtly different questions and answers we are diluting SO and making it harder for people to find the answers already there.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: The subclass is deliberately exploiting the name mangling. What possible reasons someone might have for doing this seems to me to be significantly different to why it is possible.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I guess it is similar, I did search for this before but it's difficult to come up with results before you know it's to do with name mangling (or even know about name mangling)- surely more questions makes it easier to find one of the answers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow, that is really horrible.

This works because methods that begin with a double-underscore - the `__bar` method in `A` - are name-mangled as a very basic way of simulating "private" functions in Python. But they're not actually private, they're just prefixed with `_classname`. So the coder here is taking advantage of this to override the so-called private method in A.

This works, but you shouldn't ever do it. (In fact, you should almost never use the double-underscore private attributes anyway, but that's a different discussion.)

Comment: "This works, but you shouldn't ever do it" - well sometimes you just have to do it, like when you don't maintain the package the base class comes from.

Comment: @bruno I don't disagree, but my phrasing remains accurate: you *shouldn't* do it.

Answer (score 3):

This is so classes can have attributes that are not accidentally mixed up with the attributes of subclasses. This is seldom necessary which is why you don't see `__` prefixed attributes very often (most often I have seen Java programmers misusing it because they think it does something it doesn't do)

This code is going out of it's way to bash the class's attribute. Python won't stop you doing that, but it would be hard to find a good reason to write code like that